# How to read specific dots on an image, then export values to html automatically?

Tags: php, html, image-processing

I have an image as below

http://forkiki.com/forkita/image.iklan/question.jpg

is there a tool that is able to read the red dot on the image, then provide the output as follows

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="Pinguins" usemap="#pinguins">
<map name="pinguins">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Dot1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Dot2">
</map>
```

I am familiar with php

Comment: Ahh, I also want to hack the captcha image of black text, if its possible.

Comment: thanks for the response, what do you think the best solution to resolve the problem above ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Just try this and see https://www.recognize.im/

Comment: @kkuilla I am still confused, from where I should start to look for the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give any context as to where/why you want to do this, but maybe this will get you started. I am using ImageMagick which is free and available from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org) with command line, PHP, Perl, python, .Net bindings.

Taking your image, you can identify all the red pixels like this:

```
convert question.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill black +opaque red -fill red -opaque red out.jpg
```

which will give you this image:

[image]

If you want the pixel colours at each point, you can extract them like this:

```
convert question.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill black +opaque red -fill red -opaque red text: | more

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1024,768,255,srgb
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
1,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
2,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
....
....
729,81: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
730,81: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
725,82: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
726,82: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
```

So, if you just want the coordinates of the red dots, change the `more` to `grep red` and you will see the red pixels are at 729,81 and so on.

If the circles are too big, and you want them reduced down towards dots, you can use the morphological operator `erode` like this:

```
convert question.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque white -morphology erode:5 square out.jpg
```

and you will get this:

[image]

Comment: WOOW, thanks alot @Mark, i really appreciate your answer, i will try it..

Comment: it work like a charm, thanks again @mark, you are a savior..

Comment: yes Mark this answer answer my question, thanks again @Mark